# Controls not dimming when view controller is presented locally and alert displayed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

When I present a `UIAlertController` over a view controller, the controls are dimmed as expected.

[image]

However, if the same view controller is itself modally presented, the display of the alert controller does not dim the controls (the two buttons remain blue).

[image]

How do I make a presented view controller itself handle presentations correctly, and dim its controls?

[Here](http://benpackard.org/SO/DimTest.zip) is a small example project. The relevant code is in `MainViewController.swift`.

Comment: I don’t know why they don’t dim, but is easy to dim them yourself if you have to. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/tintadjustmentmode/dimmed

Comment: Thanks, my question is why they *don't* dim automatically and how to have them do so - I'm aware of the workarounds. I don't think it is scalable for me to manually set the `tintAdjustmentMode` to `dimmed` every time I present anything that isn't full screen, and then back again afterwards. I could understand it with some custom controls, or perhaps some nested view controllers. But this is a trivial example that should 'just work', right? I am looking for a more thorough understanding of this API, not just a quick fix.

Comment: Should also note that it is not straightforward to dim ones own views when the alert originates from the OS, for example when a camera permission alert is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best workaround I have so far is to use a customized `UIAlertController` subclass to set the `tintAdjustmentMode` alongside its appear/disappear animations, using the `transitionCoordinator`:

```
/// A `UIAlertController` that can udpates its presenting view controller's `tintAdjustmentMode` code as it appears and disappears
class TintAdjustingAlertController: UIAlertController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        animatePresentingViewTintAdjustmentMode(tintAdjustmentMode: .dimmed, forViewControllerAtKey: .from)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        animatePresentingViewTintAdjustmentMode(tintAdjustmentMode: .automatic, forViewControllerAtKey: .to)
    }

    private func animatePresentingViewTintAdjustmentMode(tintAdjustmentMode mode: UIView.TintAdjustmentMode, forViewControllerAtKey key: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey) {
        transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
            if let presentingNavigationController = context.viewController(forKey: key) as? UINavigationController {
                presentingNavigationController.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = mode
                presentingNavigationController.viewControllers.forEach { $0.view.tintAdjustmentMode = mode }
            } else if let presentingViewController = context.viewController(forKey: key) {
                presentingViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = mode
            }
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This works, but I hope not to have to pepper it throughout my code. Would still love to know a) if there is a simple way to make this work as expected, or b) if this is indeed an iOS bug, is there a more elegant workaround?

I have also submitted a radar for this: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6113750608248832